# Polyphonic sound with envelopes with JSyn does not sound good

Tags: synthesizer, jsyn

I have used the JSyn examples PlayChords and PlaySegmentedEnvelope, (both examples are easy to find), to create a simple polyphonic sound. This piece of code

```
        synth = JSyn.createSynthesizer();
        synth.add(osc1 = new SineOscillator());
        synth.add(osc2 = new SineOscillator());
        synth.add(envelopePlayer1 = new VariableRateMonoReader());
        synth.add(envelopePlayer2 = new VariableRateMonoReader());
        double[] pairs = {0.1, 1.0, 0.5, 1.0, 0.7, 0.3, 0.8, 0.0};
        envelope = new SegmentedEnvelope(pairs);
        synth.add(lineOut = new LineOut());
        envelopePlayer1.output.connect(osc1.amplitude);
        envelopePlayer2.output.connect(osc2.amplitude);
        osc1.output.connect(0, lineOut.input, 0);
        osc1.output.connect(0, lineOut.input, 1);
        osc2.output.connect(0, lineOut.input, 0);
        osc2.output.connect(0, lineOut.input, 1);
        synth.start();
        lineOut.start();
        osc1.frequency.set(440.0);
        envelopePlayer1.dataQueue.queue(envelope);
        osc2.frequency.set(660.0);
        envelopePlayer2.dataQueue.queue(envelope); // attack
        synth.sleepFor(2.0);
        synth.stop();
```

does play a fifth as expected. There is, however, a very disturbing noise played as well. How can this be improved to play just the fifth?

Comment: Please +1 the answer below. It will solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The sine waves are being added together by the LineOut.

The audio hardware can only handle audio in the range of -1.0 to +1.0. Anything over 1.0 will clip and sound bad. If you mix two sine waves with an amplitude of 1.0 then they can add up to 2.0.

Try setting the amplitudes of the envelopes to 0.4.

```
envelopePlayer1.amplitude.set(0.4);
envelopePlayer2.amplitude.set(0.4);
```

Or you can use a mixer to control the volume of the individual voices.

Answer (score 0):

I had meet too.I created a sinesweeper and connect with VariableRateMonoReader.Then the amplitude just can be 0.5 at most. Otherwise it will make noise.I have try many times, and I found the problem may be two oscs.Remove one osc then try again.